Unable to use our PowerDNS Nameservers with GoDaddy domains - Error message: "nameserver isn't registered"
We are https://elitedomains.de/, a German domain provider offering nameservers for our customers to use with external domains as well. However, we have encountered an issue when trying to use our nameservers with domains registered at GoDaddy.
When attempting to add one of our nameservers to a GoDaddy-registered domain, we receive the following error message: "We can't save your changes because this nameserver isn't registered. Verify your entry for accuracy and check with your DNS provider that this nameserver is registered."
see screenshot of error message
The records of our nameservers appear to be correct and match those of other nameserver providers, as shown here: https://unboundtest.com/m/A/ns1.elitedomains.de/GDCRCWY2
We initially suspected that the issue might be related to our infrastructure provider, Cloudflare. However, even when setting up an A-record pointing to the IP address of our nameservers on another provider and attempting to add it to a GoDaddy domain, the problem persists.
We wonder if it could be due to our PowerDNS configuration? This is our PowerDNS configuration file: https://justpaste.it/fgh9q
Has anyone else experienced this issue or have any insights into what might be causing it? We appreciate any help or suggestions you may have.
Thank you!

I would try putting the trailing dot at the end of each entry to signify that it is from the root & not a subdomain.,

we tried that out. but it didnt solved it...

UPDATE: We were wondering if the RRSIG Record can be a reason.

We are pointing a-records (ns1 and ns2) to our powerdns nameservers using Cloudflare dns.
We tried a different subdomain as nameserver (ns1.podcasthero.ch), pointing to our powerdns nameserver NS1).
We didn't use cloudflare for the new domain, so it comes without RRSIG
Result: denied with same error message on Godaddy
We tried some 3rd party nameservers that didn't run into the error message and were accepted by Godaddy

Our Nameserver:
https://dns.google/query?name=ns1.elitedomains.de
VS.
Alias for our Nameserver, not via cloudflare:
https://dns.google/query?name=ns1.podcasthero.ch
VS.
3rd party Nameserver that is accepted by godaddy:
https://dns.google/query?name=ns1.nicsell.com
We are looking for a new approach. Any ideas?

The whois glue for elitedomains.de shows the nameservers should be set to major.ns.cloudflare.com & vita.ns.cloudflare.com. However, your screenshot show the domain you are trying to configure is elitedomainz.com.with its glue records being NS31.DOMAINCONTROL.COM & NS32.DOMAINCONTROL.COM.

We solved our problem. Thanks to everybody :)
The glue record was missing in the zone of the tld-extension, i.e. in the zone of the DENIC registry.
